# knockoutJS error: Converting circular structure to JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I've encountered an error: Converting circular structure to `JSON`.

Below is the scenario -

I have called two different functions from two different bindings.

Button 1 bindings -

```
event: { keypress: $root.AddComments }
```

and this function has below definition

```
self.AddComments = function (data, event) {

try {
            var Id = 0;
            if ($.isNumeric(data.Id)) {
                Id = data.Id;
            } else {
                Id = data.Id();
            }

            var HdnSaveChanges = document.getElementById('HdnSaveChanges');
            HdnSaveChanges.value = "Unsaved";

            if (event.which == 13) {

                if (data.Comment() != "") {

                    HdnSaveChanges.value = "Saved";


                    var Comment1 = { "Description": "" + data.Comment() + "" };
                    ajaxRequest("post", "/api/myAPI/PostComment/" + (Id || "") + "/" + (loginUserId || ""), Comment1, null)
                     .done(function (result) {
                         var newId2 = [result];

                         var tempComment = new Comment(newId2[0], Id);
                         tempComment.ParentObj = data;
                         tempComment.User = tempComment.User();
                         tempComment.BadgeTypeCss("SmallBadgeType SmallBadgeType" + tempComment.User.BadgeType);
                         tempComment.CurrentLevelCss("SmallCurrentLevel SmallCurrentLevel" + tempComment.User.CurrentLevel);

                         var id = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.ids(), function (currentIds) {

                             return currentIds.Id() == Id;

                         });

                         if (id) {

                             tempComment.MeLiked = ko.observable(false);
                             tempComment.MeUnLiked = ko.observable(true);
                             idea.comments.push(tempComment);
                             idea.TotalComments(data.TotalComments() + 1);
                         }                         

                     })
                     .fail(function (jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
                         console.log("Request Failed" + textStatus + "," + error + ",," + jqxhr.toString());
                     });

                    data.Comment("");
                }
            }
            return true;           
        }
        catch (e)
        { }
    };
```

Second button binding is - click: `$root.SubmitOnClick`
and the definition goes like -

```
self.SubmitOnClick=  function (data, event) {

        var Id = 0;
        if ($.isNumeric(data.Id)) {
            Id = data.Id;
        } else {
            Id = data.Id();
        }
        ajaxRequest("post", "/api/myAPI/Update/" + (Id || "") + "/" + (loginUserId || ""), data, null)
         .done(function (result) {

             var newId3 = [result];

             var id1 = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.ids(), function (currentIds) {

                 return currentIds.Id() == Id;

             });

             if (id1) {


                 id1.MyValue1(newId3[0].MyValue1);
                 id1.MyValue2(newId3[0].MyValue2);
                 id1.MyValue3(newId3[0].MyValue3);
                 id1.TotalValue1(newId3[0].TotalValue1);
                 id1.TotalValue2(newId3[0].TotalValue2);
                 id1.TotalValue3(newId3[0].TotalValue3);

                 id1.Average = ko.computed(function () {

                     var sum = id1.TotalValue1() + id1.TotalValue2() + id1.TotalValue3();

                     if (sum > 0) {

                         return Math.round((sum / 3) * 10) / 10;
                     }
                     else {
                         return 0;
                     }
                 }).extend({ notify: 'always' });

             }

         })
         .fail(function (jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
             console.log("Request Failed" + textStatus + "," + error + ",," + jqxhr.toString());
         });

    }
```

The problem arises when I call second function after first function but the vice verse works fine.

What is making a circular call here and what could be the solution for that.

Comment: are you able to create a jsfiddle to replicate the issue?  because at the moment I don't think that there is enough information here to help you out.  Also what is the structure of the `data` that goes into the http calls?

Comment: If it can be of any help, this error comes up when one of the object properties contains a pointer to a DOM element (which you cannot convert to JSON). My guess is that `data.Comment` or `data.Id` (which you are trying to save as JSON) contains a pointer to a DOM element; eg if `data.Id === $('#some-id')` instead of `'#some-id'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding your code but I think your issue is here:

```
ajaxRequest("post", "/api/myAPI/Update/" + (Id || "") + "/" + (loginUserId || ""), data, null)
```

Why are you submitting `data` in the AJAX request? That's the click event parameter so I have a feeling this isn't necessary and/or was unintentional.

If `data` contains some information that you do need for the AJAX request I would suggest extracting the specific values out and submitting your own object.

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right "data" in the ajaxrequest is creating circular reference here. Thanks !!